# Vue 3 rellax.js usage

Tags: vuejs3

i have installed rellax.js in vue3 project.

```
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRellax from 'vue-rellax'

createApp(App).use(VueRellax).mount(#app)
```

but when i add rellax class on any components template tags its not working

```
<section class="rellax section portfolio-section pd-34" id="portfolio">
     <PortfolioComponent />
</section>
```

not working when i add class rellax in component class even doesnot show in inspect

Answer (score 0):

It looks like vue-rellax was never rewritten for Vue 3. You're likely better off to use the rellax library and import it into your components or as a window variable.

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';
    
    import Rellax from 'rellax'
    
    onMounted(() => {
      let rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
    })
</script>
```